# Android, constraintLayout with constraintDimensionRatio that fit in screen (or another constraintLayout)

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

I was happily coding a constraintLayout with a constraintDimensionRatio 1:1, that gives me a centered square with some padding.

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/board"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
        android:background="@color/black"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1:1"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

BUT, for my usecase, I had to dynamically change the ratio ; so I tried a 10:1, and I discover that my view is always vertically centered and with some padding, but overflows the screen with its height :(

Is there a way to have a fully-centered view, that works with any constraintRatio, that could be kept in its parent layout and exploiting all available space in this one ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if I fully understood, but if you want keep the ratio 10:1 but keep the view inside the parent, just change both `layout_height` and `android:layout_width` to `0dp`, like so:

```xml
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/board"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
        android:background="@color/black"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1:10"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: ... Allllriiiiight I feel really dumb, it was so simple to resolve xD I lack some skills with layout :/ Anyway, many thanks for this answer !